# Keras flow_from_directory not reading all the images in all the classes

Tags: tensorflow, keras, directory, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I am using Keras ImageDataGenerator in Google Colab.
I have 3 classes of tennis images like so:

```
FRAMES_RGB

|- bhnd --> contains about 34000 image files  
|- forehand --> contains about 34000 image files  
|- idle --> contains about 9082 image files

FRAMES_RGB_VALIDATION  
|- bhnd --> contains about 3500 image files  
|- forehand --> contains about 3500 image files  
|- idle --> contains about 1000 image files
```

However, when I run the code I get the following message:

```
Reading training and validation data...
Found 9082 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 8324 images belonging to 3 classes.
```

Therefore, I know for a fact that it is only getting the images from the idle class in the training set (everything is working in the validation set), but it still knows that there are 3 classes.

These are my generators:

```
 training_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=self._preprocessing_function,
        rotation_range=30,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,  # Randomly flip half of the images horizontally
        fill_mode='nearest'  # Strategy used for filling in new pixels that appear after transforming images
    )

    validation_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=self._preprocessing_function)

    training_generator = training_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        training_dir,
        target_size=self._target_size,
        batch_size=training_batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical'
    )

    validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size=self._target_size,
        batch_size=validation_batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=False
    )
```

Why is it only reading the idle class in my training set?

Comment: It seems even validation data is also wrong. Can you share complete code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you.

Comment: @TFer2 This is the link to the folder where I am executing everything and the notebook is "Copia de training_thetis_non_seq" . https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uKtcIwJ021zP_gMmjGrMRRwViNseXhlk?usp=sharing